# Marketing Cloud (ET) - Query more than 6 months?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I would like to query information regarding sends/jobs/opens from an Marketing Cloud account, but the information queried from Data Views only contains information from the past 6 months.

Is there any way to query for a period longer than this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. We normally extract and import tracking data to back-fill our own Data Extension copies of the System Data Views if we need more than 6 months of data.

I'm sure the SFMC folks love it when we do that.

You can extract as far back as you want with the Tracking Extracts.

Comment: Great, never knew about Tracking Extracts, thank you!

Comment: You can find it here: `Interactions > Data Extract > Create New > Extract Type, Tracking Extract`. Welcome to the most convoluted page in SFMC.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs how do you back-fill? Assuming, you APPEND by query and keep filling data in DE? How do you stop the back-filling at any point? For Example, if I want to back-fill only up-to 12 months, where to define that logic? By Date - 12 months in query?

Comment: What time frame is a good / safe to collect data? My concern is that if I am saving more than a year data then sql queries may fail or time out if we are dealing with millions of records and it may affect system's performance.

Comment: I'd recommend utilizing retention settings appropriate for your use-case on the data extensions you create.

Comment: So you recommend query like this to save data in DE? `SELECT *
FROM _Bounce WITH (NOLOCK)` Instead of doing this --> `SELECT *
FROM _Bounce WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) <= 365`  and use data retention to ignore data more than x months? In this case, I should use APPEND for saving data in DE?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs I am just trying to understand your process of back filling the data. Do you use query to get data from data views (upto 6 months) and keep on APPENDING the data via query from data views? And, back-fill the data manually by getting tracking export and importing the old files in the same DE where you are adding data views data?

Comment: I use set of tracking extracts, unzipped and imported as the backfill, then a set of queries to append incremental data.  or you can do the whole thing with tracking extracts.

Comment: Gotcha- Thanks @AdamSpriggs So do you keep filling the data in your data extensions as local views or do you use data retention too? My concern is adding millions of rows will affect performance of the system or no? In documentation there is no limit defined for data extension but just curious how far we can go in saving data. Any advise?

Comment: You should use a retention period on all DEs -- something that coincides with the range needed to support your requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76515/discussion-between-kuml-and-adam-spriggs).

Answer (score 1):

The data still exists.  Going forward, you can store it yourself in data extension.  If you need info today from more than six months ago, you will need a services engagement to get you a data extract (which you will only need one time)

Comment: what about the date range should not exceed 30 days? if I want 2 years back data?  do I have to create 24 different data extracts?